# Difference between pip, pip3.8 pip3

Tags: python, pip

I installed python 3.8. In the python folder there is a folder named 'Scripts' which contains pip, pip3.8, pip3. What is the difference among these? Are they the same? 
Can I delete pip3.8 and pip3?

Comment: What operating system are you on? Did you check whether these link to the same files? Why do you want to delete ``pip3.8`` and ``pip3``?

Comment: `pip3.8` is probably the one you want to keep. `pip3` is likely an alias or symlink to `pip3.8` (and would be updated should you install `pip3.9`), while `pip` is likely a version for Python 2 (or an additional alias to either `pip3` or `pip3.8`).

Comment: They are the same as `pip`. Just as you can type `python3.8` and `python3` and `python`. It is for if you have multiple Pip versions (e.g. pip for python 2.7, pip for 3.4, pip for 3.8, etc). EDIT — Just after posting this I saw @chepner 's comment which is even better than mine.

Comment: I want multiple version of python on my computer (I am using Windows): python 3.8 and  python 3.5 (I am using some packages which only run on 3.5..). If I call 'pip' in the terminal it will not know if I am calling the pip for python3.8 and the pip for python3.5. So I want to have pip3.5 and pip3.8 only and remove the other pip files. Does it make sense?

Comment: Arguably, this question is likely a better fit for serverfault since it is a general environment/shell question that is not specific to Python or programming, but this is extremely easy to answer (see my answer below), @alexmeeg clearly just needs a few pointers, and others who search for this may find similar value. In the future, however, serverfault might be the more appropriate place for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

> I want multiple version of python on my computer (I am using Windows): python 3.8 and python 3.5 (I am using some packages which only run on 3.5..). If I call 'pip' in the terminal it will not know if I am calling the pip for python3.8 and the pip for python3.5. So I want to have pip3.5 and pip3.8 only and remove the other pip files. Does it make sense?

You do not need to delete anything from any of your Python installations to get reasonable behavior on a system where you are attempting to support multiple projects that target multiple Python versions.

Install each Python version--in your case, 3.5 and 3.8--in distinct paths and add the appropriate paths to your [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) in your preferred order.

Paths which appear earlier in that variable's value will have precedence over paths which appear later in cases where there is an ambiguity. You should seriously consider reading about the `PATH` variable and how shells search paths for executables when you do not use absolute paths.

See below for an example (partial) `PATH` variable on a Windows system with Python 3.7 and Python 3.8 installed side by side. In the example, `pip3.8` would resolve to `pip` from the Python 3.8 installation, `pip3.7` would resolve to `pip` from the Python 3.7 installation, and `pip` would resolve the same as `pip3.8`.

```
> echo %PATH%
D:\Installs\Python38\Scripts;D:\Installs\Python38;D:\Installs\Python37\Scripts;D:\Installs\Python37

> where python
D:\Installs\Python38\python.exe
D:\Installs\Python37\python.exe

> where pip
D:\Installs\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe
D:\Installs\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe
```

Also, if you find yourself managing multiple Python versions for a single Python project, consider reading about projects like [`tox`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [`nox`](https://nox.thea.codes/en/stable/) which aim to simplify managing multiple virtual environments across multiple Python versions; or, consider looking into containers/virtualization.